# What reasons could an iframe have for not loading?

Tags: html, iframe, pixel

I think the question is pretty simple: what reasons could an iframe have for not loading its content?

This came up because I have an iframe in my site's "thank you" page to track conversions. For some reason, when using dev tools in Chrome I can't find any content inside the body or head tags inside the iframe.

But if I click on the iframe's URL, the conversion is correctly activated and I see the message "Conversion logged: true".

Could there be something in my own site preventing the iframe from loading? How can I assure that the iframe will load correctly? Could using an img pixel instead solve this problem?

Comment: Is the iframe coming from the same domain or a different domain?

Comment: @calvinf the iframe's URL is from a different domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your iframe is coming from a different domain, it is possible the domain you are attempting to serve the iframe from has a security policy which prevents you from embedding it in your page.

There are two potential technologies related to this.

1. [X-FRAME-OPTIONS HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options): page owners can specify that their content should not show in an iframe or only show in an iframe on the same origin (domain).
2. [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/CSP): has "frame-src" (non-standard implementation in Firefox) and "frame-options" (standardized) directives.  It allows setting policies for iframes similar to X-FRAME-OPTIONS.

In essence, if you're serving content from a third-party site you don't control, it's possible they may have an HTTP header or security policies in place that would prevent the iframe content from showing in your page.

More Resources:

- [CSP support (caniuse.com)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy)

Other possibilities (which I think are unlikely since it worked when you loaded the page directly):

- Ad-blocking browser extensions
- "Do Not Track" policy
- Browser extensions that block tracking tools

Answer (score 0):

Tracking elements are often blocked by browser add-ons like `Adblock Plus` and `NoScript`.
For being more specific in your case, we need an example page that is demonstrating the problem.